# making custom axes in flotgraph

Tags: jquery, flot, axes

I've read the API, but I'm not sure what I do with my data so that I get meaningful axis values.

This is a small sample of my data:

```
  $scope.data = [
    { "plate": "CAR", "date": "2016-10-21" },
    { "plate": "CAS", "date": "2016-10-23", "tags": [ "unreliable" ] },
    { "plate": "CAT", "date": "2016-10-24" },
    { "plate": "CAU", "date": null,         "tags": [ "unused" ] },
    { "plate": "CAV", "date": "2016-11-05" },
    { "plate": "CAW", "date": "2016-11-10" },
    { "plate": "CAX", "date": "2016-11-10" }
  ];
```

I hope to have the X-axis labeled with the plates, and the Y-axis labeled with dates.

Here's a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u4p8vcc0/12/

Following this example: http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/tester-9.html I've added 'mode: time' to the options, but this just defaults the range to 0-1000.

I'm still not sure how to turn my data into ticks.

(Yes, forgive the use of angular with jQuery. flot.js **requires** jQuery, so...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using `categories` mode for the x-axis and `time` mode for the y-axis and filling your `enhancedData` array with the needed data format. Replace

```
enhancedData.push([idx, item.daysElapsed]);
```

with

```
enhancedData.push([item.plate, item.dateObj.valueOf()]);
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4p8vcc0/28/) for the full example.

Comment: That's way cool. It shows me that it *can* be done. Downside is that It'll take a lot of rework to get it working right. eg. while CAS is 'unreliable', it should still appear on the x-axis (otherwise the slope is skewed), just without a data point. Because of this, what ends up happening to my data is that I need items to be there for one feature, and then not there for another.

Comment: You could add them as `[item.Plate, null]` in an `else` branch to your `if` branch.

Comment: Sorry, does not work. Treats as if there is no data point at all (CAS is not on x-axis): https://jsfiddle.net/u4p8vcc0/33/

Comment: Then you have to create a `ticks` array manually instead of using `categories` mode. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/u4p8vcc0/39/